# how can I draw a arc with goocanvasmm

Tags: c++, gtkmm

Is it possible to draw only a part of a circle with goocanvasmm:

```
m_ellipse = Goocanvas::Ellipse::create( x, y, radius.x, radius.y );
root->add_child( m_ellipse );
```

works fine and draw a full circle.

How can I draw only an arc?

Is that based on a circle or must i calculate a long list of points for a polyline? If so, is there an example anywhere?

Comment: Why don't you just check the documentation: https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas/unstable/GooCanvasPath.html

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Thanks for the hint! I did not thought that drawing arcs can only be done by using SVG. I never used path before and internet search for goocanvasmm and arc did not give any usable idea.